# How to determine if sum of any given consecutive array elements is equal to a given number in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting a coding problem which asks me to print "YES" if the sum of any consecutive array numbers is equal to the given number and "NO" if none.

Here is the question:
Prateek wants to give a party to his N friends on his birthday, where each friend is numbered from 1 to N. His friends are asking for a gift to come to the party, instead of giving him one. The cost of the gifts are given in the array Value where ith friend asks for a gift which has a cost Costi.

But, Prateek has only X amount of money to spend on gifts and he wants to invite his friends which are in continuous range such that sum of the cost of the gifts of those friends will be exactly equal to X.

If he can invite his friends, who can satisfy the above condition then, print YES otherwise print NO.

Input:
The first line contains a single integer T, denoting the number of test cases. In each test case, the following input will be present: - The next line contains two space-separated integers N and X, where N represents the number of friends and X represents amount of money which Prateek can spend on gifts.
- Next N line contains N integers, where ith line contains ith integer, which represents the Costi .

Ouput
Output exactly T lines, each containing the answer to the corresponding test case .

Constraints:

```
1 <= T <= 10
1 <= N , Costi <= 106
1 <= X <= 1012
```

SAMPLE INPUT

```
  1
  5 12
  1
  3
  4
  5
  2
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT

YES

Explanation

In the sample input, T is equal to 1. So, accordingly, in next line, values of N and X are given which are 5 and 12 respectively. In the next 5 lines, you have costi asked by ith friend. As friends numbered from 2 to 4 (inclusively) have gifts value which are {3, 4, 5}, and their sum equals to 12 - that is, the given value of X. So, the answer is YES.

my solution is here

```
b = Array.new
a = Array.new
t = gets.to_i
if t >= 0 && t <= 10
    t.times do
         n, x = gets.chomp.split.map(&:to_i)
         n.times do
         a << gets.to_i
         end
         (1..a.length).each do |num|
           a.each_cons(num).each do |pair|
            if  pair.inject(:+) == x
             b << "YES"
            else
             b << "NO"
            end
           end
         end
         if b.include?("YES")
             puts "YES"
        else
             puts "NO"
        end
     end
  end
```

Although they have accepted my answer, it does not pass all the test cases, hence I am not satisfied.Can someone help me with a correct, more efficient and elegant solution?

Comment: Your link just shows a login page.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Oh Yes..Sorry about that..I guess one has to login to see the challenge.I will post the entire question

Comment: This is not a Ruby problem, its an assignment issue - you should not ask such questions here

Comment: @ Wand Maker I thought stack overflow was to help people get solutions, learn, review and understand codes.How is trying to figure out a solution to an assignment question which will help me to learn any different?

Comment: Re: "it does not pass all the test cases". Which test cases are failing?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]

number = 5
array.each_cons(2) { |pair| puts 'YES' if pair.inject(:+) == number }
#=> 'YES'

number = 10
array.each_cons(2) { |pair| puts 'YES' if pair.inject(:+) == number }
#=> nil
```

Or when you want to return 'YES' or 'NO':

```
array.each_cons(2).any? { |pair| pair.inject(:+) == number } ? 'YES' : 'NO'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you split your answer into several parts:

1. Reading input from the user
2. Determining whether an array contains a consecutive subarray that sums to a given number
3. Printing `YES` or `NO`.

Your code is difficult to read because all these responsibilities are intertwined. Point 2 is crucial. To play nicely with points 1 and 3 it can be solved with a function that accepts an array of numbers and the desired sum as arguments and returns `true` if there's a consecutive subarray with the desired sum and `false` otherwise.

The simplest algorithm looks at all subarrays, computes their sums and compare with the desired sum.

```
def consecutive_sum?(array, sum)
  (0...array.size).each do |start|
    (start...array.size).each do |stop|
      return true if array[start..stop].inject(&:+) == sum
    end
  end

  false
end
```

`start` and `stop` mark the beginning and end of the subarray. `Array#inject` is used to compute the sum of the subarray.

I'll leave points 1 and 3 to you.